# Workaround/fix for this known Apache Storm bug?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a Storm installation running a few topologies and am seeing this error regularly:

> dropping 1 message(s) destined for Netty-Client-

It seems that this is a known bug, which is marked as resolved.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-763

But is there a stable build with a fix for this bug? It doesn't seem to be fixed in 0.9.5, and 0.10.0-beta is still in beta.

Any recommendations for how to deal with this known issue? Is there I version I can upgrade to, a workaround to avoid the bug, and anything I can due to reduce the it's frequency?

Comment: You can either upgrade to 0.10.0-beta or patch 0.9.5 by yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply, turns out patching .9.5 will not be an option for me. any idea if downgrading to .8.2 would be a smart option? or thoughts on the stability of the .10.0-beta?

Comment: No advice from my side. Sorry.